# Building an Ajax autopager using Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

The website I am building would greatly benefit from having an autopager. For those not familiar with the term, an autopager is essentially automatically loading the next page when scrolling to the bottom (think about the Reddit Enhancement Suite loading new pages of reddit so you can scroll forever).

This does not seem like a trivial task in Django. I am not sure, but I think Django's templating engine (or an extension of it) cannot do this. The alternative is passing raw Json data to the view, and rendering the page using the [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) or [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) templating engines. Afterwards when a new page is needed it can be rendered at runtime and added to the DOM.

I am not sure if purely Javascript is the right solution to the problem. Are there any other solutions which are more "in the spirit" of Django?

EDIT Clarification: I am hoping Django provides some stuff to make the task at hand work better with the things the framework already offers, for example the templating engine, or via some extensions to Django. Or, if I could render the HTML on the server and send only the part that needs to be appended to the document as-is.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if purely Javascript is the right solution to the problem. Are there any other solutions which are more "in the spirit" of Django?

???

Javascript is the only solution for you problem.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. I was hoping Django provides some stuff to make the task at hand work better with the things the framework already offers, for example, the templating engine (or some extensions to Django, like [http://www.dajaxproject.com/](http://www.dajaxproject.com/)